# How to hide / encrypt source code written in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, deep-learning

I had developed a standalone application on Windows for Deep Learning / Computer vision in Python 3.X using various standard python libraries such as pandas, numpy, TensorFlow, Keras, Yolo, PyQt ...etc. I want to deliver this application to my client but without source code.

Can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: Convert into pyc files. Use the same python version as your client.

Comment: If you want to create an application to deliver to a client, sans the source code, then perhaps Python is not the language of choice. You may look into `pyinstaller` library, but, from personal experience, I can tell you that any `.exe` created this way will be impractically large in size!

Answer (score 0):

"I want to deliver this application to my client but without source code."

Can you clarify this process?

If you just want to deliver this service to your client you can just use HTTP/POST to let users upload their data to you, then you run these data on your network on the server, and finally, just return the prediction result to them.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but I want to deliver this total application to client, he will load data at his premises. I do not know what is the best way to do that.

Comment: @parag it is hard actually. You can make your program an app like .exe so that he will not be able to read your source codes easily. But if he/she really wants to hack your code, it is always possible to make it (use the disassemblers).